# How to display a link field with its link text in a twig template

Tags: 8, theming

A content type includes a link field `link` that accepts Link text.

A user inputs the URL `/target` with the Link text "Go to target".

How do I get twig to generate

```
   `<a href="/target">Go to target</a>`
```

I have tried what I've found by reading, including

- `{{ node.field_link }}` (crashes)
- `{{ node.field_link|render }}` (crashes)
- `{{ node.field_link.value }}` (does nothing)
- `{{ node.field_link.0.url }}` (displays `/target` but not as a link and ignores the link text)
- `{{ node.field_link.uri }}` (displays `internal:/target` but not as a link and ignores the link text)

Seems like there must be a one-step way to accomplish this.

Comment: Doesn't twig just output this by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ node.field_link }}` and `{{ node.field_link|render }` crashes because `node.field_link` of type [FieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/class/FieldItemList/8.2.x) not a rendered array.

Instead of using `node` variable use `content` variable like `{{ content.field_link }}` or even `{{ content.field_link.0 }}` it works.

Comment: Perfect. So simple, and yet I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: Helped a lot! In my case that was link field in paragraphs, worked like: `paragraph.field_link.0.url|render`